# Refactor Javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

i need help with refactoring below block of code. I was asked to avoid using let and to use const, how can i use constant here as i need to return all the options having possible match id.

```
    const findRecordExists = (options, possibleMatchId) => {
  let item;
  options.forEach(option => {
    option.waivers.forEach(waiver => {
      if (waiver.waiverNameId === possibleMatchId) {
        item = option;
      }
    });
  });
  return item;
};
```

Example of options would be :

```
options: [{
  name:Abc
  waivers: [ {waiverNameId :1}, {waiverNameId:2} ]
}]
```

Comment: What do you want as your result? An array of all objects which have a `waiver` with the inputted `possibleMatchId` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `filter` to iterate over the `options` array, returning whether `.some` of the `waiverNameId`s match:

```
const findRecordExists = (options, possibleMatchId) => {
  return options.filter(
    ({ waivers }) => waivers.some(
      ({ waiverNameId  }) => waiverNameId === possibleMatchId
    )
  );
};
```

Or, if you don't like destructuring:

```
const findRecordExists = (options, possibleMatchId) => {
  return options.filter(
    option => option.waivers.some(
      wavier => wavier.waiverNameId => waiverNameId === possibleMatchId
    )
  );
};
```

Since the result is being immediately returned from the `findRecordExists` function, there isn't even any need for an intermediate `item` (or `items`) variable.

Answer (score 0):

That's okay.

Using `const` to declare an identifier only makes the value of the identifier unchangeable if the value of the identifier is a JavaScript primitive e.g a number or a boolean.

If the value of the identifier is an object or an array (an array is a type of object in JavaScript), using `const` to declare it doesn't mean that the value of that object identifier cannot be changes. It only means that the identifier cannot be reassigned.

To refactor your code **using const**, use the code listing below

```js
const findRecordExists = (options, possibleMatchId) => {
  const optionsWithPossibleMatches = [];
  options.forEach(option => {
    option.waivers.forEach(waiver => {
      if (waiver.waiverNameId === possibleMatchId) {
        optionsWithPossibleMatches.push(option);
      }
    });
  });
  return optionsWithPossibleMatches;
};
```

If you want to skip intermediate steps of creating variables to store each option that matches your condition, you can use the `filter` method as prescribed by @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 0):

You can re-factor with using `find` method. This will simplify and avoids the `item` variable.

```js
const options = [
  {
    name: "Abc",
    waivers: [{ waiverNameId: 1 }, { waiverNameId: 2 }]
  }
];

const findRecordExists = (options, possibleMatchId) =>
  options.find(option =>
    option.waivers.find(waiver => waiver.waiverNameId === possibleMatchId)
  );

console.log(findRecordExists(options, 2));
console.log(findRecordExists(options, 3));
```